# Direct traffic through a LB with AWS EC2 Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm using EC2, I've got a server instance set up and I'm using an Elastic IP which points to my instance.

What I'm trying to achieve is to automatically route all http traffic to https as my server's only listening on 443, and I want to keep it this way. I think to do this I need a Load Balancer to do the routing (for example: [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/))

However after hours of searching I don't see how the Elastic IP can point to a LB? I only see options to point it to an instance or a network interface, and a network interface looks like it can only point to an instance.

Any pointers of at least where to start? Or is this the best way to ensure all traffic is routed through 443? If there's an end to end tutorial on how to do this even better! I've not done server config in many years, and I'm pretty new to AWS.

Comment: Why do you need the EIP? Isn't DNS resolution of the ALB sufficient?

Comment: @jarmod, I was under the impression the LB's couldn't guarantee you a fixed IP, which would change the CNAME too if the IP changed, as they're based on the IP in EC2 aren't they? I'll go research, maybe I'm wrong!

Comment: Right, they can't. I'm asking why having a static IP is important to you.

Comment: @jarmod, so that I configure the A Record of the domain name to point to the server, that's how I have it set up at the moment anyway!

Comment: This thread might help you: [pointing a domain name at ALB](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/8gsuvi/pointing_a_domain_name_at_an_application_load/).

Comment: @jarmod, thanks a lot, I'll take a look, I assumed the CNAMD would change, but I may be assuming wrong! This looks like the way to go though, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

> I don't see how the Elastic IP can point to a LB?

This is because  **EIP can't be associated with LB**. If you require a static public IP address, then you should either use [network load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/network-load-balancer/) or use [global accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/?blogs-global-accelerator.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&blogs-global-accelerator.sort-order=desc&aws-global-accelerator-wn.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&aws-global-accelerator-wn.sort-order=desc) for [application load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/application-load-balancer/).

The [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/) about redirecting HTTP to HTTPS is correct and this is how the redirection is usually done. ALso, when you front your instance(s) with LB you don't need EIP nor even public IP address for your instance(s). Its LB's responsibility to forward internet traffic to your instances.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, so that explains why I can't work out how to connect the two! I'll go do some research on routing protocols on Network LBs, but I assume it's similar Application LB's

Comment: @Stu No problem. NLB and ALB work differently. If you can, I would stick with ALB. Its easier and applicable to most use-cases.

Comment: Ah ok, well I basically just need to solve the http to https problem, I'm only using an Elastic IP as that's the easiest way to point the DNS to! Do you know of any documentation on a better way to run the DNS so I can use a LB to run the protocols?

Comment: @Stu I have no better link then the one you provided. This is how you redirect HTTP to HTTPS using ALB. There's not much to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in Nginx or in your other web server configuration , if you dont want to do that using ELB

like this

server {

```
listen 80 default_server;
server_name my_app.com;
return 301 https://my_app.com$request_uri;
```

}

if you are using Apache then

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>    
ServerName example.com   
ServerAlias www.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

OR

As @Marcin said , simply go with ELB , dont need to have EIP for this.. ELB correctly redirect HTTP to HTTPS if you added action Rule to ELB

Comment: Thanks @Ravindra, I'm using node unfortunately so neither nginx or apache on the server, so will be easier to do it through the network setup than on the server I think